# Does following SQL query invoke an entire table scan?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Does the following query use full table scan?

If so, is there a way to avoid the full table scan?

```
  SELECT a.title, 
         COUNT(*) AS `count`
    FROM b
    JOIN a ON a.id = b.a_id
GROUP BY b.a_id
```

Please note that following indexes exist:

`a PRIMARY id`

---

`b PRIMARY c_id THEN a_id`

`b INDEX a_id`

---

Here are the results of explain:

```
id  select_type  table  type    possible_keys  key      ref         rows  extra
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   SIMPLE       b      index   a_id           a_id     NULL        7     Using index
1   SIMPLE       a      eq_ref  PRIMARY        PRIMARY  dev.b.a_id  1
```

Comment: The explain output is pretty clear that it is using indexes at every stage. A full table scan would be indicated by "ALL" under the `type` column. Why do you think a full table scan might be involved?

Comment: @Ted I wasn't sure what I was looking for. I am designing the schema at the moment and I want to know whether this would full scan because when table is large it would be too slow. The alternative schema would involve high-maintenance counters so I am hoping on this instead.

Comment: @Ted, why not post as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explain output is pretty clear that it is using indexes at every stage. A full table scan would be indicated by "ALL" under the `type` column. This looks like it will use the indexes to access exactly those records from which you need data. (The counting is also done using only the index.) See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html) for more info on interpreting the output of EXPLAIN.